# Why was my Very Low Quality flag declined?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41893422). It is too broad, asks for recommendation of an external library and shows minimal research effort. I could not see any way that the community could edit this question to be on-topic, so I flagged it as "Very Low Quality".

I have encountered similar posts in the past and have flagged them as "Very Low Quality" without issue, but this time my flag was declined.

Why would a "Very Low Quality" flag be declined in this case?

Comment: Why did you decide to flag this as "very low quality" instead of voting to close it? At least two of the problems you cite with this question are actual close reasons! That's what we do with questions that are not on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Even if that were a high-rep user who had asked the question (it's not), they wouldn't get preferential treatment. The rules are applied equally to all users. This is not why your flag was declined.

The reason your flag was declined is because the question should have been *closed* instead. Don't flag things for moderators to close. Flags should only be raised for seriously problematic content, something whose presence is actively harming the site and needs to be immediately deleted.

On questions that need to be closed, you should just vote to close yourself (or flag as "should be closed" if you don't have close-vote privileges).

Comment: I said _relatively_ high. And I flagged it for _deletion_.

Comment: Your title and closing sentence both ask if "high-rep users" get preferential treatment, so that's the question I'm addressing. Regarding your flag, all I can see is that you flagged it as "very low quality", when you could have simply cast a close/down vote. You shouldn't be using flags for content that doesn't actually require a moderator's intervention.

Comment: I have flagged similar questions for deletion and these flags were considered helpful. The deletion rules might be what they are and I don't care how much the question gets downvoted. I have moderated and administrated public forum pages myself. Maybe it's worth to stop a moment if moderation rules need clarification. I know that moderation is not easy, but if users sees rules inonsistently applied, this won't help either. You can see my post as an attack, but maybe it's wortth to think about it. The solution could be also to reject _all_ my deletion flags, which would be also ok. Then I know.

Comment: @Sefe Nobody accused you of attacking anybody. The bulk of the flags that were marked "helpful" were *automatically* marked helpful because the question was subsequently closed and/or deleted by other people *correctly* using their close/delete votes. The majority of your flags that were handled by actual human moderators were declined. Please, don't flag content unless it's extremely egregious or you don't have some other means (close/down/delete votes) of addressing it.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify the automatic handling of flags. It is by no means obvious to users how the moderation system works in the background. All that users see is a yes/no decision. Users don't know how moderation rules are applied unless you give them clear feedback (as in your last comment).